# ASP.Net 5 vnext input/output json formatters don't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

In my asp.net 5 vnext (beta 6) web api project, my input/output json formatters settings don't seem to have any effect what-so-ever on serialization of the objects. 
I can't find anywhere why ...

Has anyone came across this?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Configure.
        services.ConfigureMvc(o =>
        {
            // Input Formatters.
            var jif = new JsonInputFormatter()
            {
                SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                }
            };

            o.InputFormatters.Clear();
            o.InputFormatters.Add(jif);

            // Output Formatters.
            var jof = new JsonOutputFormatter()
            {
                SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                }
            };

            o.OutputFormatters.Clear();
            o.OutputFormatters.Add(jof);
        });
    }
```

With these settings I still get this as a server response:

{"Result":"Error","Reason":null,"Time":1439068137652,"Messages":null}

Comment: This link might help http://www.strathweb.com/2014/11/formatters-asp-net-mvc-6/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with this code:

```
        services.ConfigureMvcJson(o =>
        {
            o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            o.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
            o.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Though, with it I don't get the luxury of separating between the input and output formatters.